# Can there be scenarios where an overfitted model in machine learning cannot be generalized?

Tags: machine-learning-model, overfitting, generalization

Is it always possible to generalize an overfitted model? I know there are ways to handle overfitting, but can there be scenarios where overfitting cannot be handled in machine learning?

Comment: What do you mean by "handling" and "generalizing" the overfitted model?

Comment: Of course there are: if the features are not related to the target, then a ML model can only learn noise. Same thing if there are too few instances to represent the true population.